# Alternative definition of conditional independence

Tags: probability

I'm reading a paper named "Conditional Independence in Statistical Theory" by A. P. Dawid. The paper shows some alternative definitions of independence:
X and Y are independent iff:

1. $p(x, y) = p(x)p(y)$

2. there exist two function $a(x)$ and $b(y)$ such that: $p(x, y) = a(x)b(y)$.

Dawid said that it is simple to verify that the two definitions are equivalent. However, I have spent several hours to solve this but failed.

Comment: X and $x$ are the same thing, right ?

Comment: I think that $X$ is the random variable while $x$ is some specific value of that random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One implication is trivial (hereafter, I assume $X$ and $Y$'s probability distributions are continuous wrt Lebesgue, ie have densities — this is implicit in your question). As for the other, suppose there exist $a$,$b$ satisfying (2). As a first consequence, $a,b\geq 0$.
Fix any $x$. By definition,
$$
 p_X(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} p(x,y)dy = \int_\mathbb{R} a(x)b(y)dy =  a(x)\underbrace{\int_\mathbb{R} b(y)dy}_{K_b}
$$
so in particular $b$ must be in $L_1$, and $a\propto p_X$ (up to a factor $K_b$). Similarly, for any $y$
$$
 p_Y(y) = \int_\mathbb{R} p(x,y)dx = \int_\mathbb{R} a(x)b(y)dx =  b(y)\underbrace{\int_\mathbb{R} a(x)dx}_{K_a}
$$
so that $\forall(x,y)$ 
$$
p(x,y) = \frac{1}{K_a K_b} p_X(x)p_Y(y)
$$
Integrating both sides, we get
$$
 1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}} p(x,y)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}} a(x)b(y)dxdy = K_a K_b
$$
and thus 
$$
p(x,y) = p_X(x)p_Y(y) \qquad \forall x,y
$$

Comment: I tried to use some rules but forgot to use the integral. Thank you so much, it's really simple now.

Comment: A small error is that $p_X(x) = K_b a(x)$ and $p_Y(y) = K_a b(y)$ so that $p(x, y) = (1/(K_aK_b)) p_X(x)p_Y(y)$

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

They are not--the first one is more restrictive than the second, asking that the random variables X and Y are independent *and with the same distribution*.

One may want to replace 1. by 3. $p(x,y)=p(x)q(y)$, then 3. and 2. are equivalent. To show this, note that 3. obviously implies 2. and that, if 2. holds, then $\alpha=\sum\limits_xa(x)$ and $\beta=\sum\limits_yb(y)$ are such that $\alpha\beta=1$ hence $p(x)=a(x)/\alpha$ and $q(y)=b(y)/\beta$ solve 3.

(For continuous distributions, use $\alpha=\int a(x)\mathrm dx$ and $\beta=\int b(y)\mathrm dy$ instead.)

Comment: Possibly Dawid was following the unfortunate practice of using the same symbol, $p$, to refer to two different density functions, and expecting the reader to infer that they're different since the variables used as arguments are different variables.  This gets done all too often.  It's obnoxious.  The meanings of $f_X(3)$ and $f_Y(3)$ are different, and the difference is not in the argument to the function.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I agree with every point in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$$
p(x,y) = a(x)b(y)
$$
Then
$$
\int_{\text{$x$-space}} a(x)\,dx\cdot\int_{\text{$y$-space}} b(y)\,dy = \iint_\text{product space} a(x)b(y)\,dy\,dx = \iint_\text{product space} p(x,y)\,dy\,dx = 1.
$$
Let
$$
A = \int_{\text{$x$-space}} a(x)\,dx.
$$
Then
$$
\int_{\text{$y$-space}} b(y)\,dy
$$
must be $1/A$ since the product is $1$.  Therefore $x\mapsto \dfrac{a(x)}{A}$ and $y\mapsto Ab(y)$ are density functions, and when you multiply them you get $p(x,y)$.

Suppose there were other denisty functions $c$, $d$ such that $c(x)d(y)= a(x)b(y)$.  Then we would have $\dfrac{c(x)}{a(x)} = \dfrac{d(y)}{b(y)}$, at least at points where the denominator is not $0$.  Then we would have
$$
\frac{c(x)}{a(x)} = \text{something not depending on $x$}
$$
(since $d(y)/b(y)$ does not depend on $x$).  In other words $c(x)/a(x)$ is a *constant*.  Thus $c(x)$ and $a(x)$ are essentially the same function.

Comment: I'm not sure that we can deduce $a(x)/A$ and $Ab(y)$ are equal to $p(x)$ and $b(y)$.

Comment: @tunght_53 : I've added something explaining how one can conclude that.

Comment: Thank you, @Michael Hardy. I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer but that is really helpful.